# Getting and error when making a domain in my python code

Tags: python

I need some help with my code. I made a basic grading system that looks liek this

```
grade = float(input("Enter the your grade:\n"))
if 81 < grade:
    if 98 <= grade <= 100:
        grade = "B+"
    if 91 <= grade <= 97:
        grade = "B"
    if 81 <= grade <= 90:
        grade = "B-"
if 71 < grade <= 80:
    if 78 <= grade <= 80:
        grade = "B+"
    if 74 <= grade <= 77:
        grade = "B"
    if 71 <= grade <= 73:
        grade = "B-"
if 61 < grade <= 70 :
    if 68 <= grade <= 70:
        grade = "C+"
    if 64 <= grade <= 67:
        grade = "C"
    if 61 <= grade <= 63:
        grade = "C-"
if 51 < grade <= 60:
    if 58 <= grade <= 60:
        grade = "D+"
    if 54 <= grade <= 57:
        grade = "D"
    if 51 <= grade <= 53:
        grade = "D-"
if 50 > grade :
   grade = "F"

print(grade)
```

When I try to run it I get this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    if 81 < grade:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong because I have zero clue XD

Comment: you don't `return` the grade from a function, rather you set it to the _same name_ each time you find a matching range and then future ranges check against the new string!

Comment: because the ranges are all the same, you can find out the letter grade from the first digit and `+-` from the second

Comment: Hi @Siddharth, please select one of the answers or ask follow up questions so the community knows to move on and support others. Thanks, good luck, and welcome to Stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in the first line you're assign `grade` to a float value. Then, you compare this float value with a int value (which is OK). When a condition matches, you assign `grade` to a string value and compare this string value with a int value. Since you can't do that, the error is raised. There are two solutions:

- Use `elif`s:

```py
grade = float(input("Enter the your grade:\n"))
if 81 < grade:
    if 98 <= grade <= 100:
        grade = "B+"
    elif 91 <= grade <= 97:
        grade = "B"
    elif 81 <= grade <= 90:
        grade = "B-"
elif 71 < grade <= 80:
    if 78 <= grade <= 80:
        grade = "B+"
    elif 74 <= grade <= 77:
        grade = "B"
    elif 71 <= grade <= 73:
        grade = "B-"
elif 61 < grade <= 70 :
    if 68 <= grade <= 70:
        grade = "C+"
    elif 64 <= grade <= 67:
        grade = "C"
    elif 61 <= grade <= 63:
        grade = "C-"
elif 51 < grade <= 60:
    if 58 <= grade <= 60:
        grade = "D+"
    elif 54 <= grade <= 57:
        grade = "D"
    elif 51 <= grade <= 53:
        grade = "D-"
elif 50 > grade :
   grade = "F"
```

- Use a new variable:

```py
grade = float(input("Enter the your grade:\n"))
if 81 < grade:
    if 98 <= grade <= 100:
        grade_str = "B+"
    if 91 <= grade <= 97:
        grade_str = "B"
    if 81 <= grade <= 90:
        grade_str = "B-"
if 71 < grade <= 80:
    if 78 <= grade <= 80:
        grade_str = "B+"
    if 74 <= grade <= 77:
        grade_str = "B"
    if 71 <= grade <= 73:
        grade_str = "B-"
if 61 < grade <= 70 :
    if 68 <= grade <= 70:
        grade_str = "C+"
    if 64 <= grade <= 67:
        grade_str = "C"
    if 61 <= grade <= 63:
        grade_str = "C-"
if 51 < grade <= 60:
    if 58 <= grade <= 60:
        grade_str = "D+"
    if 54 <= grade <= 57:
        grade_str = "D"
    if 51 <= grade <= 53:
        grade_str = "D-"
if 50 > grade :
   grade_str = "F"
```

The best solution is to use both solutions above.

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the float value with a string. I think each of your `if` statements (after the first one) should be changed to `elif` statements so it doesn't keep getting tested.

This changes the code completely, but I decided to store the lower bounds and assume grade can never be above 100.

```
# Appears like it's impossible to get any A grades, but we have double B ranges.
gr_table = [
    (98, 'B+'), (91, 'B'), (81, 'B-'), (78, 'B+'), (74, 'B'), (71, 'B-'),
    (68, 'C+'), (64, 'C'), (61, 'C-'), (58, 'D+'), (54, 'D'), (51, 'D-'),
    (0, 'F')
]

grade = float(input("Enter the your grade:\n"))
for lim, val in gr_table:
    if grade >= lim:
        grade = val
        break
```

Comment: Also, I see you're arranging an "outer" set of `if` statements for each letter grade. I think this isn't needed for the way your logic works.

Answer (score 0):

You code logic is right, however, you should make this as a function and return the answer.
Here:

```
if 81 < grade:
if 98 <= grade <= 100:
    grade = "B+"
if 91 <= grade <= 97:
    grade = "B"
if 81 <= grade <= 90:
    grade = "B-"
```

If we say the grade is 95, and after the `if 91 <= grade <= 97:` it will become "B" and then, when you `do if 81 <= grade <= 90:`, it's going to clash. You can make this a method and use return or you could use another variable to store the result like:

```
grade = float(input("Enter the your grade:\n"))
result = ''
if 81 < grade:
    if 98 <= grade <= 100:
        result = "B+"
    if 91 <= grade <= 97:
        result = "B"
    if 81 <= grade <= 90:
        result = "B-"
if 71 < grade <= 80:
    if 78 <= grade <= 80:
        result = "B+"
    if 74 <= grade <= 77:
        result = "B"
    if 71 <= grade <= 73:
        result = "B-"
if 61 < grade <= 70 :
    if 68 <= grade <= 70:
        result = "C+"
    if 64 <= grade <= 67:
        result = "C"
    if 61 <= grade <= 63:
        result = "C-"
if 51 < grade <= 60:
    if 58 <= grade <= 60:
        result = "D+"
    if 54 <= grade <= 57:
        result = "D"
    if 51 <= grade <= 53:
        result = "D-"
if 50 > grade :
   result = "F"

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your challenge is that by using `if` statements everywhere, after your grade gets assigned a letter, 'B+' for example, then all the other `if` statements still evaluate and you're now comparing a string to an int.

You can use the `elif` framing to avoid errors like this, and also simplify, shorten, and de-nest your code. The way the `if`, `elif`, and `else` construct works is python will evaluate the `if`, if that's `False`, then it moves through the `elif`s until it finds an `elif` that evaluates to `True`. Then it executes the code block in that one `elif` and stops.

If none of the `elif` statements evaluate to `True`, then it executes whatever is in the `else` block:

```
grade = float(input("Enter the your grade:\n"))
if 98 <= grade <= 100:
    grade = "A+"
elif 91 <= grade < 98:
    grade = "A"
elif 81 <= grade < 91:
    grade = "A-"
elif 78 <= grade < 81:
    grade = "B+"
elif 74 <= grade < 78:
    grade = "B"
elif 71 <= grade < 74:
    grade = "B-"
elif 68 <= grade < 71:
    grade = "C+"
elif 64 <= grade < 68:
    grade = "C"
elif 61 <= grade < 64:
    grade = "C-"
elif 58 <= grade < 61:
    grade = "D+"
elif 54 <= grade < 58:
    grade = "D"
elif 51 <= grade < 54:
    grade = "D-"
else:
    grade = "F"

print(grade)
```

Lastly, I replaced your double 'B' grades with 'A', so now a 98 is an A+ instead of a B+.